# Use less than in criteria for DSUM on excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[In cell D1003, I am using the DSUM function to sum up everything in cells B2:F1001 under the heading "MO Orders" which has a date of 23-dec-15.  I want to create another summation of everything in the database <23-dec-15, again under "MO Orders" - how can I do this?]

[Image attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vOmr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just putting <23-dec-15 in C1003 worked for me. You have to be careful when putting dates in expressions (e.g. 23/12/15 can be interpreted as a division instead of a date), but this is read as a string and seem to work correctly.

You could add this as another set of criteria in rows 1004 and 1005 if you wanted to keep both sets of criteria.

Comment: I tried this, but the value returned is 0 when it should be 72.  Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if the dates are stored as text? Then 23-dec-15 would match as a string, but <23-dec-15 wouldn't work